# Initializing iterator pointer : Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, memory

I was trying to make Queues in C (as a class project). The demo code they provided is for Borland Turbo C. I am trying to rebuild the program via `gcc`. While the code runs perfectly in Turbo C, it throws error in `gcc` during run-time as `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)`.

I have not included unnecessary parts of the code. Tried and tested it line by line.

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};

struct queue {
    struct node *front;
    struct node *rear;
};

void initQ(struct queue *q) {
    q->front = q->rear = NULL;  //      Error : Segmentation Fault! (core dumped)
}


void main() {
    struct queue *Q;
    initQ(Q);
}
```

I am sure the problem is related to the version of C in the compiler. As Turbo C is quite ancient it doesn't support latest fixes. I am getting similar `Segmentation Fault` error in various other parts of code like :

```
void displayQ(struct queue *q) {
        struct node *temp;
        temp->link = q->front;  //      Error : Segmentation Fault! (core dumped)
 }
```

**Question 1 : Why does gcc give such run-time error? (in this code)**

**Question 2 : Why does the code work fine in Turbo C but not gcc?**

**Question 3 : Is there an alternative to such programming style?**

Comment: Ad Question 2: The code is invalid in every version of C, examining why it appears to work with Turbo C will depend on several other information. E.g. the platfrom. Also note, that it may appear to work for small queues but fails for larger input, or may fail immediately if run again and so on. It seems, that `Q` happens to hold some random value which can be dereferenced (what it's pointing to and what other data you might overwrite is a different thing). Also note, that it could have appeared to work when compiled with Gcc as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1 : Why does gcc give such run-time error? (in this code)

Because the code is incorrect - you dereference an initialised pointer.

---

> Question 2 : Why does the code work fine in Turbo C but not gcc?

It does not work fine, it simply does not detect the error.  16 bit DOS code does not have the benefit of memory protection and virtual memory.  It cannot tell the difference between real memory belonging to your process (in DOS there is no process memory because it is not multitasking. The whole DOS subsystem runs in its own protected VM.  The only protection you may have is dereferencing of a NULL pointer.  The value of the pointer will resolve to some non-deterministic memory location and may appear to work correctly, until something else uses that same memory location for some other purpose - that may never happen, that may happen sometimes, or it may happen when executed on a different machine - you cannot tell.

Most often the problem will manifest itself long after the code is written when your application becomes larger and uses more and more memory.  If the location referenced happens to be in your code space, you will have the interesting prospect of the code changing randomly while executing.  Such bugs are very difficult to find, because teh cause and effect are often separated by both time and code proximity.

Had your written :

```
struct queue *Q = NULL ;
```

You may have had a runtime error report.  That does not make the code any more correct, but it does make it more likely that such errors will be detected.

---

> Question 3 : Is there an alternative to such programming style?

It is not a matter of style, it is a matter of correctness.  However if you always initialise your pointers on declaration to point to either a valid instance or NULL you could avoid the issue or at least achieve early detection of the error.

Even though in this case in the 32bit code the error was detected at runtime, that is by no means guaranteed - your initialised pointer resides on the stack, which in other cases is likely to contain values that are valid addresses in your process, and you will just be stomping on your own data.

Answer (score 4):

You need to reserve space (using `malloc`):

```
struct queue *Q = malloc(sizeof(*Q));
initQ(Q);
```

or better yet `calloc`:

```
struct queue *Q = calloc(1, sizeof(*Q));
/* initQ(Q); you don't need this, calloc set all members to NULL */
```

Don't forget to call `free(Q);` at the end.

Comment: +1 for a nice `malloc()` call using `malloc(sizeof *Q);` vs. `malloc(sizeof(struct queue));`.

Comment: Skipping `free(Q)` may cause the program to throw `Segmentation Fault!` error?

Comment: No, skipping `free` a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) occurs

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> void initQ(struct queue *q) {
>     q->front = q->rear = NULL;
> }
> ```

In your code `q` is not initialized when you use it and points to some random address. Try:

```
struct queue Q;
initQ(&Q);
```

Comment: No more errors in `initQ()`, but I get same error in `temp->link = q->front;` from `displayQ()` function.

Answer (score 2):

`Q` has not been initialized to point anywhere in particular, meaning it's an *invalid* pointer value. When you pass it to `initQ`, you try to dereference it using the `->` operator.  Attempting to dereference an invalid pointer leads to *undefined behavior*, which can mean anything from the code working as expected to crashing to corrupting data.

Whatever initial, indeterminate value `Q` has under Turbo C, it's in an accessible region of memory (it's still an *invalid* pointer, though), so you don't get the segfault that you do in gcc.

When you call `initQ`, `q` *must* point to a valid object.  You could call `initQ` on 
an existing queue instance, like so:

```
struct queue Q; // Q is an instance of struct queue, not a pointer to it
initQ( &Q );
```

Or, you could create a pseudo-constructor that dynamically allocates memory for a new
queue object and calls `initQ` on it:

```
struct queue *create_queue_element( )
{
  struct queue *q = malloc( sizeof *q );
  if ( q )
    initQ( q );
  return q;
}
...
struct queue *Q = create_queue_element();
```